# ng bootstrap 6.0.0 and angular 9.0.0 int.d.ts missing from typescript compilations

Tags: angular, typescript, upgrade, ng-bootstrap

After upgrading to angular 9 and bootstrap 6 I'm getting this error.
I've run ng add @angular/localize and this error now appears.

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/localize/init.d.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: *******/node_modules/@angular/localize/init.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format 
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (*******/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:937:23)
    at *******/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31
    at runMicrotasks ()
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
 @ ./app/scripts/polyfills.ts 22:0-32
 @ multi ./app/scripts/polyfills.ts

Comment: reinstallation of node_modules could help

Comment: Still getting the same error.